# How could I write a length function in which gives back the length of the interval?

Tags: c++, function, constructor

```html
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class Interval {
 double x,y;
  public:
    Interval(double,double);
    Interval();
 void print();
 double absz();
 void save(char*);
};

Interval::Interval(double x, double y) {
 this->x = x;
 this->y = y;
}

Interval::Interval() {
 cin >> x >> y;
}

void Interval::print() {
 cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")the length of the interval:";
}

double Interval::absz() {
 return abs(y-x);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 Interval *i = new Interval();
 i->print();
 cout << i->absz();
 delete i;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

I'm writing a program in C++, which can calculate the length of a closed interval. My question is: how could I write a function which would give back the length of the interval? I appreciate every help.

Comment: Ehh, end-of interval minus start-of-interval? This seems pretty trivial; if you know the start and end, just return the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've already written one. Namely, `Interval::absz` calculates length of interval.